# Is there a Peter-Weyl-Theorem over the real numbers?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, real-numbers, harmonic-analysis

I'd like to know: Is there a Peter-Weyl-like Theorem over the real numbers? If so, can you provide a reference?

With "over the real numbers" I mean that the representations considered act on vector spaces over the real numbers.

Best,
Leon

Comment: Do you have any ideas in mind for what might replace the various uses of the spectral theorem or the Schur lemma in the proof? Eventually you always need something like that. If you are prepared to assume your group is a matrix group (the proof of which usually uses P-W theorem) then the statement that matrix coefficients of the finite-dimensional unitary representations are dense in $L^2(G)$ will follow from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Yes, assuming matrix groups is an option for me. If this will be the most helpful answer, I would give you the bounty for such an answer if you elaborate on it.

But there's some issues:
- There are probably more matrix coefficients than we need. For example, for SO(2), we have a decomposition $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}(SO(2)) = \widehat{\bigoplus}_{m \geq 0} V_m$, where $V_m$ is the m'th order irrep and $V_m$ is generated by $\cos(m \cdot x)$ and $\sin(m \cdot x)$. Thus, the irreps here do *not* appear with their dimension, but only once. I would like to know what the general pattern here is.

Comment: And no, I don't know what might replace the spectral theorem and Schur's Lemma (I actually never read a proof of Peter-Weyl Theorem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what Knapp calls the Peter-Weyl theorem. Often people mean just statement (1), but the other follow easily from it.

Let $G$ be a compact real Lie group. Then

1. The matrix coefficients of the finite-dimensional complex irreducible representations are dense in $L^2(G)$;
2. If $\{\Phi^\alpha\}$ is a maximal set of mutually inequivalent finite-dimensional irreducible complex unitary representations of $G$, and $(d^\alpha)^{1/2}\Phi_{ij}^\alpha\}$ is the corresonding orthonormal set of matrix coefficients, then this second set is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(G)$.
3. Every irreducible complex unitary representation of $G$ is finite-dimensional.
4. Every unitary complex representation of $G$ is an othogonal direct sum of finite-dimensional irreducible representations.
5. Let $\Phi$ be a unitary complex representation on a Hilbert space $V$. For every irreducible representation $\tau$,let $E_\tau$ be the orthogonal projection onto the closure of the sum of invariant subspaces of $V$ isomorphic to $\tau$.Then $E_\tau=(\dim\tau)\Phi(\overline{\chi_\tau})$, where $\chi_\tau$ is the character of $\tau$. The $E_\tau$ are orthogonal idempotents, and every $v\in V$ satisfies $v=\sum_\tau E_\tau v$.

To prove (1) one can either assume $G$ is a matrix group or not. If not, one uses the Hilbert-Schmidt theorem, and I think this argument actually goes through for real representations. If one does assume that $G$ is a matrix group, then the span of the matrix coefficients of finite-dimensional irreducible real representations

- Separates points, by looking at the given representation of the matrix group
- Vanishes nowhere, by looking at the same;
- Is an algebra, as if $f$ and $g$ are matrix-coefficients of representations $V$ and $W$, then $fg$ is a matrix coefficient of (a suitable irreducible subrepresentation of) $V\otimes W$.

Therefore by compactness of $G$, the matrix coefficients are uniformly dense in the continuous functions, hence dense in the norm topology in $L^2(G)$.

Point (3) follows from (4) and (4) follows from (1). The argument over $\mathbb{C}$ goes through also for $\mathbb{R}$: it is essentially Zorn's lemma and then using (1) to prove that the orthogonal complement to a maximal set of orthogonal finite-dimensional irreps itself contains a finite-dimensional irrep, which of course is a contradiction.

As you identified, the problem comes with (2) and (5). For (2), as you corrected an earlier version of this answer saying, while matrix coefficients of nonequivalent representations will be orthogonal, different matrix coefficients of same representation no longer need to be. For example, the circle group acting on the plane via rotations.

The proof of (5) requires in the end the existence of eigenvalues as it involves Schur's lemma. In your example the exact problem is that abelian groups can have two-dimensional real irreps, so in this case $V_m$ appears once in $L^2_\mathbb{R}$ so that its complexification gives two one-dimensional irreps each occuring once. In general I think that unless you can say that every irreducible representation occuring in $L^2_\mathbb{C}(G)$ arising as a subrepresentation of a complexified representation over $\mathbb{R}$ is contributed only by a single isomorphism class of representation over $\mathbb{R}$, there won't be an easy formula. I can't say I've thought about this (the only interesting part, as it turns out) at all, though.

Comment: Hello,

after some reflection, I don't see why point (2) follows from (1). What we do obtain is that for inequivalent irreducible representations, their matrix elements are perpendicular. 

But in the proofs that I saw so far that matrix elements of equivalent (as representations) or even isomorphic (as unitary representations) irreducible representation are perpendicular, usually I saw Schur's Lemma used, particularly the version that shows that an endomorphism of an irrep is a multiple of the identity.

Comment: See Lemma 19 here and its use in Proposition 20:

https://math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/pw.pdf

Comment: Indeed, I was saying nonsense. (look, embarrassingly enough, at the matrix coefficients for the action of the circle group acting by rotation on the plane. They are definitely not not pairwise orthogonal.) But it is still true that (1) implies (3); the proof of three uses only the density statement. I'll edit this now, thank you!

Comment: I now btw. still think that the most important parts of the Peter-Weyl Theorem go through also over R. See tthis discussion with Terrence Tao:

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/the-peter-weyl-theorem-and-non-abelian-fourier-analysis-on-compact-groups/#comment-564129

Once I'll have this worked out completely, I'll write an answer myself, but this may take some time.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Yes, (1), (3), and (4) hold for the reasons I gave. As we've seen, (2) and (5) are not true, for the reasons you pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the Peter-Weyl theorem can be formulated for complex and real representations simultaneously using the ideas from the book by Bröcker and tom Dieck "Representations of compact Lie groups", Chapter III, Section 6, Exercise 4.

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\lambda$ be an irreducible representation of a compact topological group $G$ in a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-linear space $E$ with $G$-invariant inner product. Let $D(E)$ be the set of linear operators in $E$ that intertwine $\lambda$ with itself. If $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$, then $D(E)=\mathbb{C}$, while if $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, then $D(E)$ may take three values, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{H}$, the skew field of quaternions.

Let $E^*$ be the linear space, dual to $E$, that is, the set of $\mathbb{K}$-linear functionals over $E$. It is a *right* $D(U)$-linear space via composition. On the other hand, $E$ is a *left* $D(U)$-linear space via evaluation. The tensor product $E^*\otimes_{D(U)}E$ is defined. A simple bookkeeping shows that the dimension of this $\mathbb{K}$-linear space is equal to $\frac{(\dim E)^2}{\dim D(E)}$. If $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$, then the denominator is equal to $1$, if $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, then it may take three different values: $1$, $2$, and $4$.

The map that maps the tensor product $x^*\otimes y$ to the continuous function $f\colon G\to\mathbb{K}$, $f(g)=x^*(\lambda(g^{-1})x)$, can be extended by linearity to all of $E^*\otimes_{D(U)}E$. The image of this map is a finite-dimensional subspace of $C(G)$, call it $E_{\lambda}$. It is exactly the subspace grnerated by the matrix entries of the representation $\lambda$.

The Peter--Weyl theorem becomes:

1. If $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are not equivalent, then the intersection of the spaces $E_{\lambda_1}$ and $E_{\lambda_2}$ is equal to $\{0\}$.
2. The set of finite $\mathbb{K}$-linear combinations of the elements of the spaces $E_{\lambda}$ is dense in both $C(G)$ and $L^2(G)$.
3. The space $E_{\lambda}$ carries the direct sum of $\frac{\dim E}{\dim D(E)}$ copies of the representation $\lambda$, an the Hilbert direct sum of all these representations is equivalent to the left regular representation of $G$ in $L^2(G)$.